# undefined index error when checking that a file is selected to upload or not

Tags: codeigniter, file-upload

I have a form which has an upload button.  Before uploading a file I need to check if the user selected a file or not.  Because of that I use

```
if(isseet($_FILES['pic']) && $_FILES['pic']['size'] > 0)`
```

The problem is I get an error which says undefined index:pic

`pic` is the name of my upload button in my form.  I searched for answer but can not find any thing to solve this problem.

What should I do to remove this error?

Comment: could you post your code in the question

Comment: I found the answer.My form did not have enctype attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This probably happening because you are missing `enctype="multipart/form-data"` from your form opening tag.  If you are using the CodeIgniter form helper this attribute will be added to your form opening tag if you use the following function

```
form_open_multipart()
```